# An anime with a female main character with a spiral on her forehead

Tags: arjuna

I watched this anime way back when I was small, so I don't remember the details. I'm not sure, but I think it was an anime movie. It was aired on Animax India.

I think the name of the anime was a girl's name. Somewhere in the middle of the movie, some guy explains how the spiral is somewhat of a universal symbol, and how the earth is somewhat shaped like a spiral. The girl has a monster helping her, and there's this guy who helps her with her powers at first, but he turns out to be the villain in the end.

The story takes place in a modern city. The only identifiable thing that I remember is the spiral. I think she gets it on her forehead, along with her powers to control a huge robot like creature.

That's all I can remember. It would be great if anyone knows this anime.

Comment: Can you add more information, using [this guideline as hint](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892#892)?

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like a comic I've read called [Meridian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_%28comics%29), although Meridian, was only on paper, and it was also American

Comment: Also sounds reminiscent of TTGL, but the timeline is way off and it's not a movie.

Comment: Spiral as a Yin-Yang spiral or spiral like an archimedes spiral (kinda like the Uzumaki Clan symbol)

Comment: Your wording seems to suggest the spiral appears on the protagonist's forehead during the story, and it wasn't always there, and also that you're not sure if it was on her forehead. Could you confirm these are true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be *[**Earth Maiden Arjuna**](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=107)* (2001)? I have never seen it, but it seems to deal with Earth, so there could be a "universe" theme. There is a modern setting. There is a female protagonist, and the title is based on the her name, Ariyoshi Juna. She has a magatama on her forehead which I think could be mistaken for a spiral.

[image: Ariyoshi Juna]

She also has a superhero form, if that is familiar.

[image]

Synopsis from AnimeNfo:

> When Ariyoshi Juna has a bad accident, her spirit turns to light and rises up out of her body into the night sky where she gets a glimpse of Earth a few months in the future. What she sees is the Earth on the brink of total destruction, ruled by the merciless demon forces called the Raajas. Then Chris Hawken hands Juna a power stone and tells her to use it to save the Earth. The power stone gives her the ability to call up an aura suit, that activates and enhances a person's dormant special powers.

Comment: @Ero Sennin I think it is arjuna. Because the OP says it was aired in Animax india(this is the oly anime i can think of, that animax india telecasted for the short period it lasted in india) and the guy helps her out  turns out to be the anti hero at the end is Chris. The huge robot like creature could be raaja a type of worm sort of thing. Also the reason he would think it was a movie was because it was aired in India as a marathon for Diwali. All the episodes followed one another and the series had reruns of the marathon twice.

Comment: Im the op and i think this is it. I will have to watch it to confirm... and yes i think it could have been a marathon.. thank you so much ! Still not sure though but thanks.. this is the closest answer and thanks to all others who responded . :)